# JS script in website won't run when it's a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm making a basic start page to replace the "blank" option on Firefox, it's basically just an HTML website with some JS scripts added for some functionality. I added a script for a real time clock, which works fully when run as a website, but for some reason when I run it as an add-on, the scripts don't load (e.g. the clock doesn't appear) and I get this error in the console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

I've taken a look at the `content_scripts` and `user_scripts` manifest keys, but I'm not quite sure where to start with those or if I'm even barking up the right tree with them.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is the Javascript in a separate file (clock.js) or it is in some `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: The clock is in its own js file. Would the CSP care if it is?
[edit: I do actually have a second script for the search bar that is inside of some `<script></script>` tags]

Comment: How are you loading the script in your manifest?